# Advice/experience on testing MPI code with CppUnit

Tags: mpi, cppunit

I've got a codebase where I have been using CppUnit for unit testing. I'm now adding some MPI code to the project and I'd like to unit test some abstractions I'm building on top of MPI. For example, I've written some code to manage a single-producer/multiple-consumer relationship where consumers ask for work and the producer serializes the next bit of work to send to the consumer, and I'd like to test just that interaction with a test that generates some fake work items in a producer, distributes them to consumers, which then send some kind of checksum back to the consumer to make sure everything got distributed and nothing deadlocked etc.

Does anyone have experience of what works best here? Some things I've been thinking about:

1. Is it reasonable to have all processes execute the test runner so that they all execute the test functions in the same order? Or is it better to have only the master run the test runner and have it send broadcasts to the slaves to tell them what to do next (presumably with some kind of lookup table to map commands to test functions)?
2. Is it sane in any way to use CPPUNIT_ASSERT inside the slaves, or should all information be sent back to the master for assertions? If slaves can assert, how should all the results be combined to get a single output log?

   How should one handle test failures, such that the exception thrown in one process doesn't cause synchronization problems e.g. another process is waiting for an MPI_Recv for which the matching MPI_Send will now never happen?